# Controller does not get called while rendering erb and hence unable to redirect user to login page after session timeout - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-timeout

I have a `check_login` method implemented in `ApplicationController` that would redirect the user to login screen if his session times out.

But I have a tab on my screen which has multiple subtabs - when the user clicks on any of the subtabs, an `erb` template is rendered.

After session timeout, when the user clicks on any of the subtabs, the corresponding `erb` template for that subtab is called; but none of them hit the controller. Hence my `check_login` method does not get called and the user does not get redirected to the login screen.

How can I fix this issue?

This is the session timeout check I have in place in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :check_login, :apply_layout

  def check_login
        logger.info "ApplicationController check_login"

        if session[:current_user]
              set_current_user
        else
              render :partial => 'sessions/login.html.erb'
        end
  end
```

This is `erb` code for the tab I was referring to which contains multiple subtabs:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="message" style="background-color:limegreen">    </div>
<div id="error_message" style="background-color:#FF1133">    </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills" style=" margin-top: 20px; ">
       <li class=" cfs nav-item active"> 
         <a data-toggle="tab"  class="nav-link active" href="#dbr">
       Application SubTab 1         
         </a> 
       </li>
       <li class="cfs nav-item"> 
         <a data-toggle="tab" href="#dtr" class="nav-link">
       Application SubTab 2
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="cfs nav-item"> 
         <a data-toggle="tab" href="#cpl" class="nav-link">
       Application SubTab 3
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-content tabstyle"  >
 <div id="dbr" class="tab-pane fade show active" >
   <%= render 'application_subtab1/table' %>
 </div>
 <div id="dtr" class="tab-pane fade">
    <%= render 'application_subtab2/table' %>
 </div>
 <div id="cpl" class="tab-pane fade">
   <%= render 'application_subtab3/table' %>
 </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() { 
$(document).on("click", "#dbr", function(event){

  $.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/application/check_login"
    dataType: 'script'
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

When the above `erb` or the `erb` of the subtabs are called, is there a way to call the controller so that my `check_login` gets executed?

Or should I be doing something else as a clean approach?

What's the solution for this issue?

Please help!

I tried adding the below ajax call in the erb shown above:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() { 
$(document).on("click", "#dbr", function(event){

  $.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/application/check_login"
    dataType: 'script'
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

But this ajax call does not call the `check_login` method. What is wrong in this ajax call?

Comment: your "render" is already rendering your templates on the first call, so it obviously never calls the controller later. You could add an ajax call on the tabs which checks timeout/login and redirect to login it user is no longer

Comment: @Fallenhero - Thanks much for your reply! If I make an ajax call from one of my erb files to my ApplicationController::check_login method, will that solve my issue?

Comment: remember the renders are executed on the first call (when user was sill logged in) and all ajax calls are also made then. you need to hook your ajax call to the change tab callback.

Comment: I am guessing you are using jquery tabs. So see documentation for events for jquery tabs. The event you probably need is "activate" or "beforeActivate"

Comment: @Fallenhero - Thanks much for your inputs - I had made an ajax call (I have updated my original question with the code for this ajax call) - but that does not seem to work. Could you please point me to what I'm doing wrong? (also would you be able to give me a sample code on how to hook ajax call to change tab callback please? Thanks much!)

Comment: I tried both `click` and `activate` -  neither seem to work :(

Comment: but you are using jquery? see here http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

Comment: maybe something like
`$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {$.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/application/check_login"
    dataType: 'script'
    });}
});`

Comment: Just to get clarity, can you confirm me it is not because of turbolinks. Can you wrap the ajax code inside $(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function(){ ...}) instead of only on ready and see if it helps @m.beginner ?

Comment: @PrasathRajasekaran - Thank s much for your reply. I have got around to solving this issue; but I have a different issue now though. The ajax call works fine for me, but (inside the controller function that is called by the ajax call) I have a `redirect_to` call that takes the user to login screen after session timeout; the redirect_to DOES get called just fine (I added debug lines both before and after the `redirect-to` call and they both get called fine but the `redirect_to` does not take the user to login screen; it just does not seem to be doing anything at all! Could you pls help!

Comment: I even tried `redirect_to login_path, status: 301` since 302 is temporary redirect and 301 is permanent redirect; but no effect at all!

Comment: Can you try the following @m.beginner - render :js => "window.location = 'your_path_here' "

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change your `check_login` method to redirect to login, instead of render the themplate:

```rb
def check_login
  logger.info "ApplicationController check_login"

  if session[:current_user]
    set_current_user
  else
   #render :partial => 'sessions/login.html.erb'
   redirect_to login_url # Set in your routes.rb
   return # To avoid double render error
  end
end
```

Then make an AJAX call to `check_login` when user clicks on any of the tabs and you should be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(document).on("click", "a.nav-link", function(event){

    $.ajax( {
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/application/check_login"
      dataType: 'script'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the ajax call you mentioned. I also replaced render partial with redirect_to as you suggested. But the ajax call does not seem to work. Could you please guide me what the issue is.

Comment: Please, show us how you are making the AJAX call. Is is hitting the controller? Also, check your browser's developer tools (Ctrl-shitf-i), the network tab should log the request.

Comment: thanks for the reply again. I have updated my original question with the code that makes the ajax call (hope this is what you were asking for). I looked at the developer tools in network tab - I'm afraid the controller is NOT being called. The network tab does not get any udpates when I click on the first subtab for which I had added the ajax call. Pls help!

Comment: You are welcome. Change `$(document).on("click", "#dbr",...)` to `$(document).on("click", "a.nav-link",...)` to fire the event when you click on the tabs.

Comment: I tried this - `<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function() { 
    $(document).on("click", "#dbr", function(event){
        
      $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/application/check_login"
        dataType: 'json'
        });
      });

    $(document).on("click", "a.nav-link", function(event){
        
      $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/application/check_login"
        dataType: 'json'
        });
      });
     });
</script>`  That did not work. Also, what is `a.nav-link`; pls pardon my ignorance - I am pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: It's a CSS selector, meaning "any 'a' tag with class nav-link". See my edited answer.